# How can I repair Unity after trying to install macOS theme from noobslab? Icons and dock vanished!

Tags: themes, live-cd

Last night I successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, and then I tried to install Mac OSX Theme following [this noobslab article](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/mac-os-x-lion-for-Ubuntu-1204-precise.html).

But after I installed the last thing, GNOME Tweak Tool, I ran compiz and my Ubuntu bar disappeared, then the system froze, so I restarted, and now all I see is wallpaper; no icons, no bar.

Now I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD. It's all I can use, live CD.

And one other thing, I have Windows 7 64-bit, and it's full of spyware and trojans. Can I clean it from my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

there is many anti-virus for linux which can be used to clean windows viruses and trojans.

- [Avast Home Edition](http://www.avast.com/linux-home-edition)
- Clam Anti-Virus - to install run `sudo apt-get install clamtk`

You should do clean install because there would be so many files that are changed or created. It would be very quick solution.

Comment: I too vote for a clean install and to make sure you know what you are doing each time you issue a "sudo" command in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I also would recommend a clean installation because your system files are mainly corrupted .  And it's possible to wreck your Ubuntu install with Compiz or GNOME-Tweak alone if you don't use it properly.  So this should give you a lesson to not install anything anonymous.

And if you really want to install a Mac Ubuntu Theme, read [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/45817/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-mac-os-x/).  It's much more easier.

But first, do a clean install of Ubuntu.  Here are the steps.

1. Grab a Windows recovery media or installation CD.  You should see this on  a recovery media and if you have a Installation CD choose the Repair Your Computer option.
   [image]
2. Open the Command Prompt, then type `bootrec /fixmbr` into the Command Prompt.
   [image]
3. Reboot and boot into Windows.  If your Windows is full of viruses and you can't even boot into it, try [starting your computer in safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode), or scan your windows drive with the [tools that virpara provided](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142769/how-to-recover-all-ubuntu-12-04-system-files-from-live-cd/142775#142775).
4. Go to Start, right click Computer, then select Manage.  Then select Disk Management from the sidebar.
   [image]
5. Right-click your Ubuntu partitions and select "Delete"
   . **Check before you delete!**
6. Then, right-click the partition that is on the Left of the free space.  Select "Extend Volume".  Go through the Wizard and Finish it.
   [image]
7. Install Ubuntu the usual way.
8. Reboot!